# Show Qt3D stuff inside QWidget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget, qt3d, qwindow

So I felt all warm and fuzzy inside after [reading](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/07/01/qt3d-2-0-technology-preview/) that **Qt3D** has re-emerged in a **v2.0** and is in fact becoming a part of **Qt5** soon and that parts of it is already available for testing as a tech preview.

I set out with a simple plan, I would have **Qt3D** working inside a widget in my existing **C++/widgets** based application. However the only example I could find that shows how to use **Qt3D** from **C++** is called [basicshapes-cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-basicshapes-cpp-example.html), and it shows some shapes rendered in a separate OpenGL/Qt3D prepared `window` (class that extends `QWindow`) as opposed from a `QWidget`.

Now I read about the role of `QWindow` vs. `QWidget` and how it all hangs together neatly, but I am still struggling to understand how I can port the **Qt3D** code from the `basicshapes-cpp` program to run inside a `QWidget`. What are the basic steps that need to observed?

Comment: For the moment, just use `QWidget::createWindowContainer`. Proper QWidget integration should be coming in 5.8 / 5.9.

Comment: Sweet! Put it in an asnwer and I will accept it :)

Comment: So just to clairfy, even if there is a new QOpenGLWidget, that cannot work with Qt3D?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's meant for user-provided GL code. An "equivalent" solution (i.e. a "proper QWidget") is probably easy to write, it's just going to miss the 5.7 release though. (The other piece of the puzzle missing is a way to control Qt3D rendering from the outside, i.e. have a custom driver for Qt3D and allow its integration in foreign GL code)

Comment: @peppe Are there any updates on the issue? I'm currently with Qt 5.12 at it seems there is still no solution. And no documentation :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extraction of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231012/how-to-render-in-qt3d-in-standard-gui-application/49090506#49090506#2) shows how it works:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>

class Qt3DWidget
      : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget *container;

public:
    explicit Qt3DWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

};

Qt3DWidget::Qt3DWidget(QWidget *parent)
   : QWidget(parent)
{
    auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    // put Qt3DWindow into a container in order to make it possible
    // to handle the view inside a widget
    container = createWindowContainer(view,this);

    // ... further stuff goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody is interested, I implemented an actual Qt3D widget. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget).